# Randomly slow wifi connection on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, networking, internet

I know many other posts have been made about having slow wifi on Ubuntu 16.04, but I have yet to find a fix that actually works for me.

I recently setup Ubuntu 16.04 to run on my Lenovo PC alongside Windows 10.
I haven't had any other issues, but from the beginning I noticed that sometimes my internet will work fine, but occasionally it will become extremely slow and sometimes just time out and not load any pages (gives me a "no internet" error in chromium.

This is very odd because my wifi works perfectly on Windows 10, and on my other devices. It also shows a perfectly fine connection on the top right corner where it shows signal strength.

tldr; wifi will work normally for a bit, but randomly become extremely slow/time out.

My network information:

```
*-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8821AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: wlp4s0
       version: 00
       serial: c8:ff:28:80:43:ab
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
```

Edit:
my iwconfig results (i put censored to hide my last name in wifi ssid):

```
wlp4s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"censored_5G"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.22 GHz  Access Point: 10:86:8C:70:6D:F1   
          Bit Rate=200 Mb/s   Tx-Power=17 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=48/70  Signal level=-62 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:48   Missed beacon:0

enp1s0    no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had regular lag-spikes (3000-4000ms) about every minute because NetworkManager kept actively looking for other Networks in the area, though i was connected. It did not really break the connection but was really annoying in some cases.

My solution was to use [wicd](http://wicd.sourceforge.net) as an alternative to the default NetworkManager.

First i uninstalled NetworkManager, but after a while i had to install it again(profiles with passwords+connection via umts modem) and they both seem to run fine in parallel, when NetworkManager is told not to automatically connect to the specific network.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to disable the power management of your wireless adapter?
You may do it by editing /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf (as sudo) and changing the "wifi.powersave" option from 3 to 2. Try this on the terminal:

```
sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf
```

then change:

```
wifi.powersave = 3
```

to:

```
wifi.powersave = 2
```

, and then type Ctrl+o,  and Ctrl+x. Reboot the machine and check the Power Management status by typing "iwconfig" on the terminal.

Hope it helps! :D

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I’ve tried this, and it’s off already and it didn’t do anything unfortunately.

Comment: Did you compare the output of iwconfig before and after doing this change (between reboots, of course :P )? It would be interesting to see what iwconfig outputs anyway, could you paste it here?

Comment: I added the iwconfig results in edit: on the main post, hope it helps.

Comment: At least in my case, I'm pretty sure following those steps doesn't "disable" power management, it just changes the wifi powersave. Even after reboot, when I use iwconfig, "Power Management:on" is still included in the output, no matter what I add in /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf. Am I doing something wrong, or am I just confused :P