# Suddenly having extremely slow wifi on Ubuntu 18.04 (RTL8821CE)

Tags: networking, wireless

I recently set up kubuntu on a relatively modern PC and for the first day the internet (WIFI) speeds were fine. The next day however, I am getting speeds of under 1 mbps, whereas usually I get around 100 mbps. I checked from a different machine and verified that I was actually getting around 100 mbps and it was only an issue with this computer.

```
epsilon@epsilon:~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A2 
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:c821]
        Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [103c:831a]
        Kernel driver in use: rtl8821ce
        Kernel modules: 8821ce
epsilon@epsilon:~$ uname -a
Linux epsilon 4.18.0-15-generic #16~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Feb 7 14:06:04 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I have tried the following solutions:

- [Slow wifi connection ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1148030/slow-wifi-connection-ubuntu-18-04)
- [Randomly slow wifi connection on Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/965184/randomly-slow-wifi-connection-on-ubuntu-16-04)

But haven't had any luck

Interestingly, when I reboot, it's fine, but after a while it becomes slow again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been sometime ago (and I thought this was patched) but is your Android linked to the same WLAN?

I recall that there has been issues like this in times past when an Android OS was on the same WLAN at the same time, and your description reminded me of my own experience with it.

Comment: I think thats the issue. When I remove my phone from the wifi the speeds instantly go faster. Do you know a fix for it?

Comment: My issue went away with an update to my cell phone.

Comment: Does your router support QOS?